# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON

Tags: javascript, fetch

Al consultar a una mock api, primero tuve el problema de habilitación del CORS que logré solucionarlo agregando la extensión *Moesif CORS* en Google Chrome.
El problema ahora es que me figura el siguiente error cuando consulto a la api

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 6
> Promise.then (asíncrono)
> getProducts @ tienda.js:9 window.onload @ tienda.js:12
> load (asíncrono)
> (anónimo) @ tienda.js:1

```js
const getProducts = () => {
    fetch("https://apimocha.com/mybusiness/products", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((userJson) => console.log(userJson));
  };

  getProducts();
```

Puede ser que sea porque el json venga vacio, y si es esta la razón como puedo solucionarlo? es porque estoy usando una mock api?

Comment: Haciendo la petición desde Firefox, dice que no puede parsear correctamente desde la línea 2, columna 5. Por descarte, como dice que el token no esperado es _i_, entonces se hace referencia al _id_: **no tiene dobles comillas**. No es un JSON válido: [los nombres de las propiedades deben tener doble comilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto puede servirte, al menos como punto de partida
Al volver de la promesa se hace una copia de la respuesta en **devuelto** luego al aplicar el método json si tiene éxito pues haces lo que corresponde (es el **va bien** de este código).  Pero si da error (json error) pues abre la parte de error del promise, recupera el dato devuelto le aplica text (en general si hay un error puede leerse en formato de texto) y lee el contenido.

```
    fetch("https://apimocha.com/mybusiness/products",{
                method:'GET', 
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
                })
     .then(
         response=>{
            devuelto = response.clone();
            return response.json();
         }).then(
              data=>console.log("va bien"),
              error=>{
                  console.log("Error de JSON: ");
                  return devuelto.text().then(
                         error=>{
                                 console.log(error);
                                }
                           )
                })
```